# Qt QProcess: shell for openssh

Tags: qt, ssh, console, qprocess

I need to make a shell over OpenSSH as part of Windows 10. I can't get the output of the console application using QProcess. If an error occurs and the application shuts down, I will get the output. If ssh asks for the password, I can't get this request.

```
#include "sshshell.h"
#include <QDebug>
 
#include <QTextCodec>

SSHShell::SSHShell(QObject *parent)
    : QObject{parent}
{
    process = new QProcess(this);
    process->setReadChannel(QProcess::StandardOutput);
    connect(process,SIGNAL(readyRead()),this,SLOT(ReadyReadSlot()));
//    connect(process,SIGNAL(readyReadStandardOutput()),this,SLOT(ReadOutputData()));
//    connect(process,SIGNAL(readyReadStandardError()),this,SLOT(ReadOutputData()));
}

void SSHShell::startSSH()
{
 
     qDebug()<<"startSSH()";
     process->start("ssh.exe", QStringList()<< "-D"<<"5555" <<"-N"<<"xxxxxxxxx@xxxxxx.com");
     qDebug()<<process->
 
}

void SSHShell::ReadOutputDataSlot()
{
    qDebug()<<"ReadOutputData()()";
    QByteArray ba = process->readAllStandardOutput();
    QTextCodec *codec = QTextCodec::codecForName("IBM 866");
    QString out = codec->toUnicode(ba);
    emit sendText(out);
}

void SSHShell::ReadyReadSlot()
{
    qDebug()<<"mReadyRead()()";
    QByteArray ba = process->readAllStandardOutput();
    QTextCodec *codec = QTextCodec::codecForName("IBM 866");
    QString out = codec->toUnicode(ba);
    emit sendText(out);
}
```

I've tried connecting with different signals, but the result is always the same. I can't get output if ssh interacts with me (asks for a password or key).
Help me figure it out.